# Heroku error ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, credentials

I get error when deploying via Heroku. I recreate credentials using a command `rails credentials:edit`. But I use WSL2 Ubuntu 20.4 to deploy and when I set credentials through terminal Ubuntu and successfully deploy I can't run server on `localhost:3000` on Windows , get errors: `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage`, `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError`. And when I create credentials on Windows I get the same errors after run `git push heroku master`.
Why it can happen? What I should change?
I have Rails 7.

Comment: Delete the `credentials` file in `config` folder. Then try again with the command `rails credentials:edit`

Comment: @rna Hi! Thanks for your advice. I tried this way 5 or 6 times. now I think this error in working of WSL. I didn't set environment variables for Windows programs on WSL. Perhaps if I tuned WSL, it would work. I will write later.

Comment: I added environment variables via the command ```set WSLENV=%WSLENV%:PATH/l```, but it didn't help.